# How to avoid pixel fighting when drawing on display with SetPixel?

Tags: drawing, screen

I am using `SetPixel(GetDC(0),x,y,color)` to write on the screen but as I do that, some other program updates it's screen and overwrites my drawn pixel thus the image drawn on screen appear to sparkle.

How Can I avoid this and draw something on the screen without the fear that it will be overwritten?

Comment: You can't, because the screen window is the viewport for all programs and your pixels is not drawn on your own window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The screen is a shared resource. If you want something that is exclusively yours, create a window and draw into that.